# How to remove small ticks and add frame around legend inside of the plot?

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I created plot (attached image). I need to remove the small ticks, just having integer number (removing 0.5,1.5,2.5) and putting frame around legend at end need to replace word (Orange, Blue,...) with small line with same color. This plot is one of the 15 plots that I created using "Table" code and data are too long to upload here. Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: How about `Ticks->None`? Does this work?

Comment: If you have a frame -which does not seem you do- `FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}]`?

Comment: For the legend use something like `PlotLegends -> Placed[Framed@LineLegend[{Orange, Black, Blue, Green}, {100, 1000, 5000, 10000}], {0.75, 0.4}]`

Comment: Define: `xTicks = Range[0, 3, 1];
yTicks = Range[0, 1.0, 0.2];` and after adding `Frame -> True` to the plot, use: `FrameTicks -> {
  {yTicks, None},
  {xTicks, None}
  }`